U-boot with multiple partitions
I have orangepi 3 lts with u-boot boot loader . I want to create a second swap partition and a third data partition so the first is mounted ro . I created those partitions with gparted . U-boot has a allocated area 4mb in the SD (size 1 TB ) before the first partition . The problem Is when i try to mount second or third partition. Mount Is unable even if are formatted partitions . I verified SD and card reader are ok. The problem seems in the initial area for u-boot but i dont know how to solve

Once the Linux kernel has started, u-boot's job is done. I don't see why inability to mount extra partitions would be related to u-boot at all. What exactly is the command you're trying and the error message you're getting?
